# Prevent a plain text password in RAM (Python)

Tags: python, security, encryption

I actually writing a Python module to access KeePass/KeePassX databases. My problem is that the password to the database is saved plain text in my database object:

```
def __init__(self, filepath=None, masterkey=None, read_only=False,
             new = False):
    """ Initialize a new or an existing database.

    If a 'filepath' and a 'masterkey' is passed 'load' will try to open
    a database. If 'True' is passed to 'read_only' the database will open
    read-only. It's also possible to create a new one, just pass 'True' to
    new. This will be ignored if a filepath and a masterkey is given this
    will be ignored.

    """

    self.groups = []
    self.read_only = read_only
    self.filepath = filepath
    self.masterkey = masterkey # I mean this
```

I don't know how to avoid this. The only idea I had is to store the password encrypted with a random generated key (like KeePassX does) but isn't there the problem that Python doesn't allow private members? I mean is it possible to access the random generated key from the outside of the running program? Or is the only possibility to dump the memory of the program from RAM? If the answer to the latter is `yes', than it should be increase security or am I misguided?

Either way, isn't there the problem that Python `throws' strings to the whole RAM so that there's always the possibility that the password is stored in plain text?

Many questions, I know, but it's one of the most critical points of security in this project.

Comment: Whenever you load anything into memory, even for a short while, there will always be a moment that that memory can be dumped and your key can be read out.

Comment: Why are you storing the password at all? Most systems store only a hash so that even in the event of a database compromise, hackers won't be to figure out people's passwords unless they're short.

Comment: That's not how KeePassX works: It takes the key, hashes it n times, adds a random byte string an hashes it again. This is the final key for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an OS with process memory protection (all modern OSes have this) then any code that is running in the same process will have access to the password. Other processes will not have access to data unless *you grant* specific access to a page of memory in an OS specific manner: this is one method RPG is done. The kernel has access to your memory and thus to the password, but if an attack vector comes through that path you have some serious problems.

If you have an OS with virtual memory then the page that contains the password may be written to a file that the root user has access. So a processes that is running in root could read the password from there. But if you have a rogue process running as root you have more serious problems to worry about.

Private members in objects is a language level protection that is only enforced at compilation or interpretation of the code. It has no effect on the RAM access of the data.

So in summary the password is secure while it is in the running process. You only need to be concerned if the password were saved to a file under your control or written to a stream in some manner under your control.

Answer (score 4):

Python can only be introspected from within the interpreter itself; so if you are worried about anything reading the password, that something will either have to gain access to the interpreter or it'll have to dump the process memory somehow.

The interpreter is not going to be breached unless you run some python code that opens a hole. Basically, as long as you do not use anything like the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) (which can [load arbitrary python code into the interpreter](http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2007/11/09/one-cookie-please/)), or call `eval` or `exec` on arbitrary code, you should be safe.

Of course, you cannot avoid having to store the master key in memory, if even for a brief time only. You can limit the master key being stored until the moment you need it, then wipe the variable by assigning `None` to it or something.

Comment: Due to GC, wiping the variable won't necessarily help. And if teh attacker can dump your RAM at arbitrary points, there's not much you can do anyway.

Comment: @Antimony: But the variable will no longer be accessible for introspection, which was my point.

Comment: @ Martijn: That is, encrypting the key won't increase security?

Comment: @lykaner: who would encrypt the key, and would the key need to be decrypted before use? If you need to decrypt before use, you'll have the plaintext in memory, and you are back to square one. If you have to encrypt the key, you'll have the plaintext in memory, hello square one again! The OS protects your process memory, so I wouldn't worry about that, thus encrypting the key wouldn't add anything.

Comment: If the attacker has long term access to your system with the ability to dump RAM, nothing will help short of public key encryption.